# Possible regularisation for sum of function of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, divergent-series

Consider the following sum of function of primes:

$$-\sum_{p}\ln\left( 1 - \frac{1}{(ep)^{1/2}} \right){\ln(p)}$$

Here $p$ runs through all primes and $e$ is Euler's constant.

We can see that the sum diverges.

I have following questions :

> Is possible to regularize this sum ?
> If yes, how to do so?

Any advice about going around this is welcome. Any insights in such type of problems is/are also welcome.

Related:
[A question on assigning finite values to divergent sums involving expression of primes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/390472/174361)

[On modified Euler product](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385271/174361)

I used the explicit formula for prime counting function $\pi(x)$ and integrated the given prime function with measure as $\pi(x)$.
But i couldn't deduce an exact value.

(Answer I'm expecting is zero)

Comment: You didn't say how you know the sum diverges. As $x\to 0$, $-\log(1-x) \sim x$, so for large $p$, $-\log(1-1/\sqrt{ep})\sim 1/\sqrt{ep}$. Thus the $p$-th term in the sum, for large $p$, grows like $(1/\sqrt{ep})\log(p) = \log(p)/\sqrt{ep}$. So your sum over $p \leq x$ is asymptotic (as $x \to \infty$) to $\sum_{p \leq x}\log(p)/\sqrt{ep}$ if the 2nd series tends to $\infty$ with $x$, and it does: it can be shown that $\sum_{p \leq x} \log(p)/\sqrt{p} \sim 2\sqrt{x}$, so $\sum_{p \leq x} \log(p)/\sqrt{ep} \sim 2\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{e}$.  Thus to regularize, at least subtract off $2\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: @KConrad thank you for the comment. But tried doing the Regularisation by converting the sum exactly to sum of series of log Zeta derivatives.( You can see my previous posts ) . But I'm unable to get a value so asked again.

Comment: If something's wrong with the question, please mention. I couldn't understand downvotes.

Comment: I did not downvote. The only thing “wrong” in the question is that it lacks context: why are you interested in that strange-looking sum? If you want people to see previous posts for that context, include links to them in your question.

Comment: @KConrad again thank you for the comment. I'm not that used to MathOverflow site so i don't know how it works. I thought the divergence is elementary for number theorist so i didn't gave clarification! But Regularisation seems much more tough

Comment: @KConrad again thank you for the comment. I'm not that used to MathOverflow site so i don't know how it works. I thought the divergence is elementary for number theorist so i didn't gave clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by the term “regularization”? I thought it meant “find a divergent expression so that the difference with that converges”. Maybe you mean something else.

Comment: @KConrad same meaning, sir! To assign a finite value to an infinite/divergent sum

Comment: Like the infinite sum of all the negative integers is regularized by $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$. Something along these lines may be possible seeing the expression in your first logarithm as a factor of a Euler product (not sure of how his name is pronounced in English, is the first sound in it vocalic or consonantic?).

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN thank you for the comment. Tried to regularize by classical methods in literature but couldn't do it . ( Can't derive a unique numerical value)

Comment: @KConrad Regularisation as in 'Zeta Function Regularisation'.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN : like "Oil-eir" (second syllable might have a better representation; likely in WP there is a better one)